# No sign of battery on new Kubuntu 22.04 (Lenovo MIIX 320-10ICR)

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, battery

So I recently installed Kubuntu on my Lenovo MIIX 320-10ICR, old Notebook / Tablet hybrid.

After installation, everything seemed to work fine, beside some problems with the monitor orientation, which I fixed with `xrandr -o 3` (the correct orientation is 3, idk)

Now I'm trying to figure out why the battery is nowhere to be found. I cannot see it in the brightness settings on the bottom right. [Screenshot of Brightness with text "No Batteries Available"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se3Iw.png)

Nor is `acpi -b` giving me anything. `upower -d` shows 2 devices, none of which are a battery.

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_axp288_charger


native-path:          axp288_charger
 power supply:         yes
 updated:              Mo 03 Okt 2022 13:29:17 CEST (1000 seconds ago)
 has history:          no
 has statistics:       no
 line-power
   warning-level:       none
   online:              yes
   icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
 power supply:         no
 updated:              Mo 03 Okt 2022 13:17:20 CEST (1717 seconds ago)
 has history:          no
 has statistics:       no
 unknown
   warning-level:       none
   percentage:          0%
   icon-name:          ''

Daemon:
 daemon-version:  0.99.17
 on-battery:      no
 lid-is-closed:   no
 lid-is-present:  yes
 critical-action: PowerOff
```

Under `/proc/acpi/` there is only 1 folder: 'button'. Also there is a file "wakeup". Still battery info is nowhere to be found.

If anybody can help me figure out how to get my battery to show up, I would be very grateful! Thanks in advance.

~Nuki

Comment: Brightness is a screen feature. Not sure how that would effect the battery being detected. DisplayDevice info does not to seem to fit with the question either.

Comment: @David I've seen online that the brightness usually shows the battery. Also when hovering over the brightness setting on the bottom right it says "No Batteries Available"